# Ajax seo techniques

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, seo

I've read some topics regarding enabling google to crawl ajax based sites but the information is quite controvesrial.  Is it possible? If yes can someone post a link to a tutorial please?

I most often use ajax with jquery in the following way:

1. I have a div
2. I send request to a php backend where the html is generated
3. When the response arrives i set the inner html of the div with the response i got

Is that a good approach in order to make the page seo optimized?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this link : http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Google has guidelines on how to expose your content to its crawler.

Also, this question on SO talked about the same thing : [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380)

Comment: Thread bump. [Deprecation of Ajax Crawling Docs](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and the recommended [Progressive enhancement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486/what-is-progressive-enhancement).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer taking a [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) design strategy in which the website is designed in very simple markup that the search engines can crawl and then adding AJAX on top for user experience. This typically employs "hijacking" links and forms with Javascript to override the default behavior and replace it with AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can design the Website to be fully accessible without JavaScript and after that speed up the things you want with AJAX on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

In my website, I use a normal php page and if its requesting by Ajax, its don't include the header and the footer, its just retrieve the content (body) and include it.

If the content is retrieved from a database, you can create a normal page who retrieve the content and a program just for Ajax.

Just think if you deactivate Javascript, your site continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might wont to use AJAX SEO https://github.com/laukstein/ajax-seo